# Some compressed files take long / freeze when uncompressing

Tags: windows-10

I have a zip file with a small `.dll` file inside and whenever I try unzip the file with 7zip, WinRAR or just Windows Explorer, they all just freeze and after about 5 minutes, they unfreeze and complete. It's a couple KB file and I have tried it on different computers with no problems, I tried rebooting and uninstalling my AV software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some stupid reason it was Windows Defender. And for an even more stupid reason it was on while MalwareBytes was on as well which makes no sense to me. But that's probably due to the fact that MalwareBytes doesn't count as an Antivirus because it's not. Basically for now, turn off Real-Time protection and it will work fine. Would love to hear a better solution :)